# Trying to get category name to show on category page

Tags: categories, templates

I have a template for categories and I am trying to get the catgeory name in the meta title of the page (or anywhere on the page).

I thought it was just as simple as

```
<title>{category_name} &ndash; {site_name}</title>
```

But it's not. I've tried trying to find my answer but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways of create a category page.

If you're using the "default" way, the [Channel Category Heading](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/category_heading.html) Tag can help you:

```
{exp:channel:category_heading}
    <title>{category_name} &ndash; {site_name}</title>
    {if category_description}
        <meta name="description" content="{category_description}" />
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:category_heading}
```

Remember to not put it inside a Channel Entries tag.

The [Category ID](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/cp/settings/urls.html#category-url) needs to be [in the URL](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/urls/url_structure.html#entries-and-other-things). Or the [Category URL Indicator](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/cp/settings/urls.html#category-url-segment) and the [category URL title](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/cp/channel/cat/form-cat.html#url-title).

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried to implement that but it's not working.

Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/PE9ZtAqk

And have I called the page the right thing? Screenshot of the template screen: https://s4.postimg.org/3kyuwen9p/Template_Manager_Expression_Engine.png

Comment: Your segments must match a valid category - what are your segments on the URL you're trying to access and get results on?

Comment: @drew.deakin, so get the category name is just one of your problems. I gonna update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using category ID's in the category page URL
example: www.websitename/blog/category/events

Code for category template:

```
{if segment_2 == 'category'}

{!-- code for showing category title on pages not using URL category ID's --}
  {exp:channel:categories channel='blog' style='linear'}                     
    {if category_url_title == segment_3}
      {category_name}
    {/if}
  {/exp:channel:categories}

{!-- fallback for pages using URL category ID's example: /blog/category/C4 --}  
  {exp:channel:category_heading}
    {category_name}
  {/exp:channel:category_heading}

{/if}
```